# Can't get Tabulator select editor to work correctly

Tags: tabulator

I'm new to the tabulator and am having trouble getting it to display droplist data in the correct format.

I have defined the column details thus:

```js
{
  title: "Status",
  field: "Status",
  width: 150,
  headerFilter: "input",
  editor: "select",
  editorParams: {
    listFormatter: populateStatusList
  }
},
```

As you can see, the `listFormatter` calls function `populateStatusList`. This function builds an array of strings from an already-populated structure and returns the `array.tostring()` from the function.

The tabulator droplist does show the strings but horizontally on one long line and not vertically as I'd expect (i.e. it doesn't actually drop).

Can anyone help me?

Kind regards

Comment: You write "as you can see", but there's no screenshot. You could make the question more readable by formatting the column details as a code block.

Comment: I posted in this thread, hope this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464360/tabulator-how-to-create-a-dynamic-custom-editor-based-on-another-cells-value/66881116#66881116

Answer (score 0):

The ***listFormatter*** should only be used to layout list items passed into the editor, the values for each of the items in the list should be passed into the ***values property***

```
{title:"Gentlemen", field:"names", editor:"select", editorParams:{
    listFormatter:function(value, title){ //prefix all titles with the work "Mr"
        return "Mr " + title;
    },
    values:{
        "steve":"Steve Boberson",
        "bob":"Bob Jimmerson",
        "jim":"Jim Stevenson",
    }
}}
```

In the example above the list formatter will create a list of the titles passed into the ***values*** property, prepending each with the string "Mr"