# Tabulator: How to create a dynamic custom editor based on another cell's value

Tags: tabulator

Using Tabulator, I want to dynamically create a cell's editor, either `input` or `select`, based on another cell's value.

Declaring:

```
var valueEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams)
```

I seem to be able to declare the correct editor and I have the list of values are available in the editorParams the is passed to the function API, but for the`select` I can't get the drop-down to display the values.

Here's a code snippet:

```
        var valueEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
        const item = cell.getRow().getData();

        var editor = null;

        // Use a combobox when the type is Choice, or regular input cell otherwise
        if (item.type === "Choice") {
          editor = document.createElement("select");
          editor.setAttribute("values", editorParams.values );   // <-- This is probably incorrect, but I'm unable to assign the right attribute
        } else {
          editor = document.createElement("input");
          editor.setAttribute("type", "text");
        }

        //create and style input
        editor.style.padding = "3px";
        editor.style.width = "100%";
        editor.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

        editor.value = item.value;    

        //when the value has been set, trigger the cell to update
        function successFunc(){
            success(editor.value );
        }

        editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
        editor.addEventListener("blur", successFunc);

        //return the editor element
        return editor;
      };
      {title: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 130},
      {title: 'Type', field: 'type', width: 95},
      {title: 'Value', field: 'value', width: 260, editor: valueEditor }];
```

When my row's type column is "Choice", I would like to show a combobox with, say `Choice1, Choice2, Choice3, Choice4`. Otherwise, I want to have a regular Input cell where the user can enter any values.

Answer (score 1):

It took much time and I found this way to create custom select editor of Tabulator for showing NAME base on KEY value. Hope this post helps someone.

```
var cboData = [
{
    "key": "",
    "name": ""
},
{
    "key": "01",
    "name": "OPTION 1"
},
{
    "key": "02",
    "name": "OPTION 2"
}];
var comboEditor = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
    var editor = document.createElement("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < editorParams.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = editorParams[i].key;
        opt.innerHTML = editorParams[i].name;
        editor.appendChild(opt);
    }

    editor.style.padding = "3px";
    editor.style.width = "100%";
    editor.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    editor.value = cell.getValue();

    onRendered(function () {
        editor.focus();
        editor.style.css = "100%";
    });

    function successFunc() {
        success(editor.value);
    }

    editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
    editor.addEventListener("blur", successFunc);

    return editor;
};
```

In columns setting like this:

```
  {
        title: "SELECTION",
        field: 'select_key',
        headerHozAlign: 'center',
        hozAlign: 'center',
        editor: comboEditor,
        editorParams: cboData,
        formatter: function (cell, formatterParams) {
            for (var i = 0; i < formatterParams.length; i++) {
                if (formatterParams[i].key == cell.getValue()) {
                    return formatterParams[i].name;
                }
            }
        },
        formatterParams: cboData,
    },
```

**Edited:**
If you want to load dropdown value based on another cell value, you can change as bellow:

```
var cboData = []; //Store last values based on another cell value
var comboEditor = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
    var editor = document.createElement("select");

    //GET DATA FOR THIS HERE. NOTE THAT THIS CALL EVERY TIME YOU SELECT THIS DROPDOWN
    let otherCellValue = cell.getData().OtherColName;
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: [URL TO GET VALUE],
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{ key:' + JSON.stringify(otherCellValue ) + '}',
            async: false, //wait ultil get data done
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                //assume that result is an array of data with VALUE/TEXT fields
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var item = {};
                    item.key = result[i].Value;
                    item.name = result[i].Text;
                    cboData.push(item);
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });

    for (var i = 0; i < cboData.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = cboData[i].key;
        opt.innerHTML = cboData[i].name;
        editor.appendChild(opt);
    }

    editor.style.padding = "3px";
    editor.style.width = "100%";
    editor.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    editor.value = cell.getValue();

    onRendered(function () {
        editor.focus();
        editor.style.css = "100%";
    });

    function successFunc() {
        success(editor.value);
    }

    editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
    editor.addEventListener("blur", successFunc);

    return editor;
};
```

Comment: Hi @Hieu, I am trying to incorporate the same kind. But the Value selected in the Custom editor Select is not showing on outfocus. but on click of editor its showing the selected value. Any help please

Comment: Hi @ASD, do you declare field: 'select_key' in the column definition?

Answer (score 0):

item, I think, is an object, so you would need to find your property value for your cell, like :

editor.value = item[cell.getField()]